# Skip or complete a user task with Activiti workflow

Tags: java, workflow, activiti

Is there a way to complete or skip an activiti user task with Java ? 
I implemented a TaskListener to do so but when i call this code :

```
delegateTask.getExecution().getEngineServices().getTaskService().complete( task.getId() );
```

I get this exception :

```
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: UserTask should not be signalled before complete
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.UserTaskActivityBehavior.signal(UserTaskActivityBehavior.java:146)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.signal(ExecutionEntity.java:407)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:201)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:50)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.NeedsActiveTaskCmd.execute(NeedsActiveTaskCmd.java:59)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)[415:org.activiti.engine:5.17.0]
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)[415:org.activiti.engine:5.17.0]
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:179)
    at Proxy7b61ad98_bd2d_436d_94dd_1e7381cca64e.complete(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot complete a task within a task listener since the context is still instantiated. If you want to skip a task you should do so using a gateway.

Another alternative which is only supported at the xml level (not exposed in the modeler) is to use the skip expression syntax documented in the following blog quite nicely:

https://blog.canang.com.my/2016/09/30/whats-activiti-skiptask-about/